# Which one is called first? constructor or componentDidMount or Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

As i've read online and official documentation. Order is 
Constructor-> ComponentWillMount -> Render -> ComponentDidMount and others.

```
class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('constructor', this);
        this.state = { items: [ ] };
    }

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');

    if ( toDisplay( ) ) {
        api.bringCats()
        .then( categories => {
            const tot_cat = categories.map( cat => { return {name: cat.name, link: cat.link}; })
            this.setState({items: tot_cat,})
        })
    }
}

render() { 
    console.log("render")
    //some stuff
}
}
```

> im expecting the the log to be in this order
>   1. constructor
>   2. ComponentDidMount
>   3. render

im logging `this` with `constructor` inside constructor method. im able to get value for `items` which is getting its value in `componentDidMount` why this is happening? and its logging in the correct order (constructor->didmount->render) but why im getting value of `items` even before calling `componentDidMount`.

im using `<Navigation/>` component inside `<Header/>`

```
Header extends Component{
render(){
  return (<div> <Navigation/> </div>);
}
}
```

Comment: Because by the time you go looking at the log of the constructor one, the script has had time to run and populate the instance object

Comment: How? i mean if its going to ComponentDidMount() first, it should log `componentdidmount` and populate the object right? but the order its getting logged is correct. as per the doc. its not logging like `didmount->constructor->render`

Comment: Its not calling them out of order. The object view in a js console log is a live view of the object. Meaning when the script changes that object, the console will update that view to reflect those changes. And since those calls take milliseconds to execute by the time you go to look at the log its already been updated since by that time didmount has already ran and updated the instance

Comment: In other words a console log of an object is not a __static__ view of that object at that specific time.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I'm still in confusion I'm just getting started with react and node.

Comment: Related: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196). There should also be a tiny `i` button next to the value which tells you that the output was computed at the moment the object was expanded.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with React and Node btw, just with how the console in browsers work.

Comment: This makes sense now `it is due to console.log() being queued up, and it prints a later value of the array (or object).`. It was the delay with the console. I was lost somewhere. Thank you so much. Will this happen with Firefox's console?

Comment: You could stringify the items you are interested in, like `JSON.stringify(this.props)`

Answer (score 0):

i was trying something and found out that this is working fine.

`window.cnj = require('circular-json')` */*   i added this in starting point first line so i will have access to this inside all imports. */*

`window.props = JSON.parse(window.cnj.stringify(simple));`

I can access `window.props` from the devtools and its working as expected.

`sample` can be string, arrays, normal object or circular object.